# Invariant theory for the orthogonal group and Clifford algebras

Tags: invariant-theory, clifford-algebras

The first fundamental theorem of invariant theory for
the orthogonal group $O_n(k)$ asserts that the
ring of invariants is generated by the scalar products:
a polynomial function of $m$ vectors $v_1,..., v_m \in k^n$ is necessarily a polynomial in the products $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle$.

In the real case, in dimension 2, that is for $O_2({\bf R})$,
there is a short proof using the complex numbers.
I am wondering if there is also a simple proof in higher dimension, for the $O_n({\bf R})$ case, using Clifford algebras? Any reference welcome.